# Is there a way to remove or customize Pivot transitions?

Tags: xaml, uwp

By default, Pivots transition their PivotItems in/out using a horizontal translation with an opacity fade. I'd like a way to remove them (firstly), but also customize if possible.

Things I've tried to remove them (just passing an empty `TransititionCollection` in):

```
<Pivot>
    <Pivot.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection />
    </Pivot.Transitions>
    <Pivot.ItemContainerTransitions>
        <TransitionCollection />
    </Pivot.ItemContainerTransitions>

    <PivotItem Header="Red">
        <PivotItem.Transitions>
            <TransitionCollection />
        </PivotItem.Transitions>
        <PivotItem.ContentTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection />
        </PivotItem.ContentTransitions>

        <Grid Background="Red" Width="100" Height="200" />
    </PivotItem>

    <PivotItem Header="Green">
        <Grid Background="Green" Width="100" Height="200" />
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dig into the default `Pivot` template, you will find the following part for the content:

```
<ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterTranslateTransform"/>
            <CompositeTransform x:Name="ItemsPresenterCompositeTransform"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </ItemsPresenter.RenderTransform>
</ItemsPresenter>
```

These two `Transforms` inside the `TransformGroup` manage the animation of the items, there is no `Transition` behind it. This means that setting `TransitionCollection` empty has unfortunately no effect.

Even more unfortunate is the fact that you cannot easily remove the transition, because trying trying to remove either of the two `Transforms` from the `Pivot` style will make the control not render properly. This is likely because both transforms are referenced within the controls code-behind.

As a result, it seems that customizing the animation of the built-in `Pivot` is unfortunately not possible.